# Jquery evento change llamado dos veces

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="paid_out" name="paid_out" onchange="change_payment_status(this.checked)">
        
        
    $('#paid_out').on('change', function(e){ 
        this.checked=!this.checked?!confirm('Esta acción va a anular la deuda documentada asociada a este egreso ¿Está seguro de eliminarla?'):true;
        
        if(this.checked) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation(); 
            return false;  
        }
    });
```

Cuando llamo el evento change y coloco cancelar en el confirm no ejecuta apropiadamente e.preventDefault() ni e.stopPropagation() sigue el flujo de change_payment_status y lo que quiero es detenerlo. Si saco el change_payment_status el change se detiene bien, es como si se solapara el evento onchange del checkbox con el on change.

Comment: Estás llamando dos funciones: esta es una función `$('#paid_out').on('change', function(e){ ` y esta es otra: `onchange="change_payment_status(this.checked)` Bastaría con la primera, quitando la llamada que haces in-line que por lo demás es una mala práctica. Si lo que quieres es ejecutar más cosas, que estarían en la función llamada `change_payment_status` pues invoca esa función desde dentro del bloque `$('#paid_out').on('change', function(e){` Por el momento lo que tienes es dos onchange, lo cual no tiene ningún sentido.

Comment: ok gracias, voy a usar sólo un bloque on change